# Update a system user with Chef getting Recipe Compile Error

Tags: chef-infra

I'm new to chef, but trying to update the chef-clients after uploading a new users credentials (with `knife upload`). If i then ssh into one of the servers and run `sudo chef-client` i get the following error:

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/libraries/autoload.rb
================================================================================


LoadError
---------
cannot load such file -- /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/compat_resource/gemspec


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/libraries/autoload.rb:15:in `require_relative'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/libraries/autoload.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/libraries/autoload.rb:

  8:    cookbook_version = $1
  9:  
 10:    if CompatResource::VERSION != cookbook_version
 11:      raise "compat_resource gem version #{CompatResource::VERSION} was loaded as a gem before compat_resource cookbook version #{cookbook_version} was loaded. To remedy this, either update the cookbook to the gem version, update the gem to the cookbook version, or uninstall / stop loading the gem so early."
 12:    end
 13:  else
 14:    # The gem is not already activated, so activate the cookbook.    
 15>>   require_relative '../files/lib/compat_resource/gemspec'
 16:    CompatResource::GEMSPEC.activate
 17:  end
 18:  
 19:  require 'compat_resource'
```

I'm not quite sure where to start, I have tried editing the Berksfile to say: 
`cookbook 'apt', '= 3.0.0'`
then running `knife upload` again, but no joy.

Any pointers in the right direction would be really appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Chef client are you running? `compat_resource` is deprecated and Chef client 12 is EOL. There isn't much detail on what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Hi @BrandonMiller - i'm trying to resurrect some old infrastructure, the chef client version is 11.12.8

Comment: I'm not sure exactly when 11 was ended, but 12 was EOL in April. You may want to consider updating the cookbooks and the client to at least be 13 compatible if you are going to resurrect things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably trying to use community cookbooks that are no longer compatible with your Chef version. You mention in comments that you are using Chef 11, so this is not terribly surprising. You'll need to manually check when exactly each community cookbook dropped Chef 11 support and then pin things as you have with `apt`.